# How accurate are the star prophecies?

Tags: lady-hotspur

In *The Queens of Innis Lear* and *Lady Hotspur*, most of the people of Innis Lear put a great deal of faith in the prophecies of the stars.

However, their actual track record is less clear. For instance, the stars predicted that Dalat would die on the 16th birthday of her first daughter.

However, this only happened

> because she poisoned herself specifically to fulfill the prophecy and solidify her daughters' position.

The alternative view, that of Ban, a powerful wizard, is that the stars only speak lies.

On the other hand, the people of Innis Lear, despite being quite familiar with practical magic, seem to have great deal of faith in the accuracy of star prophecies about weather, for instance, even after the fall of Lear's star-worshipping regime. One would think that stars that gave useless prophecies would not be accepted with the same readiness as in the real world.

In conclusion, how accurate are the star prophecies? Are they unavoidable fate? Complete nonsense? Mostly accurate but sometimes wrong?

Note, here I am only talking about star prophecies, not the hybrid methods that became more common after the ascension of Elia the Dreamer.